# Is there a way to make Xcode sort function list alphabetically?

Tags: xcode, macos

I could've probably found it, if I knew the name of this feature.

Say, if I click here:

[image]

The Xcode shows a popup list of functions:

[image]

Is there a setting to sort that list?

Comment: No. Xcode shows the file members in the order they exist in the file. Use the Symbol Navigator if you want an alphabetical list.

Comment: Well, that's quite a bad design of UI, IMO.

Comment: File an enhancement request.